# How to print an HTML code from a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I am developing a PHP site, and have encountered the following problem.
I have this line of code:

```
<div id="buynow"><?php echo $buynow; ?></div>
```

The variable $buynow has an html code (a paypal buy now button), and I would like to print/echo the html code that it gets processed.

With the current code, it prints the html code itself, not the desired result.

Thanks in advance

String:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Colors">Colors</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Black">Black </option>
    <option value="White">White </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Note: The value is replaced to XXXXXXXXX on purpose, in the code it is the original.

Comment: Does your web server support PHP ? or did you upload to a PHP web server, e.g. Apache?

Comment: please provide the resulting string

Comment: It is tested in XAMPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try this:

```
<div id="buynow"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($buynow); ?></div>
```

or use

```
<div id="buynow"><?php echo html_entity_decode($buynow); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I use on simple Paypal button sites is to save the button code as little php files on their own (can just be the html making up the Paypal button). Then "include" the external file at the relevant point.  It makes managing the buttons relatively easy without changing your source code.

Other than that, it seems that your page may not actually be a php page.

Comment: Thanks, however, every time I add a new product, I would have to do this. With my solution, I only have to paste the code into the admin page (which I have created myself) and fine. I do it with the price, item Id, etc. But those are only texts, this one is a php code. Another solution I may try is directly reading it into the page from the database.